# Reproducible NumPy's random results: Reseeding vs Recreating

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

According to NumPy's `numpy.random.seed()` [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html):

> This is a convenience, legacy function.
>
> The best practice is to not reseed a BitGenerator, rather to recreate
> a new one. This method is here for legacy reasons. This example
> demonstrates best practice.

However, I noticed that the results from recreating a bit generator are not reproducible. Rather, reseeding the bit generator gives reproducible results. Why is this the case? What am I doing wrong?

Also, their results differ. Why is this so? Isn't the same Mersenne Twister (MT) algorithm used?

My script for reproducing my observation is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import MT19937
from numpy.random import RandomState, SeedSequence
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seed=123456789

# Reseed a BitGenerator
np.random.seed(seed)
r1 = np.random.random_integers(1, 6, 1000)
np.random.seed(seed)
r2 = np.random.random_integers(1, 6, 1000)

# Recreate a BitGenerator
rs = RandomState(MT19937(SeedSequence(seed)))
c1 = np.random.random_integers(1, 6, 1000)
rs = RandomState(MT19937(SeedSequence(seed)))
c2 = np.random.random_integers(1, 6, 1000)

# Visualise results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axes[0].hist(r1, 11, density=True)
axes[0].hist(r2, 11, density=True)
axes[0].set_title('Reseed a BitGenerator')

axes[1].hist(c1, 11, density=True)
axes[1].hist(c2, 11, density=True)
axes[1].set_title('Recreate a BitGenerator')

plt.show()
```

[image: results]

Comment: "However, I noticed that the results from recreating a bit generator are not reproducible. Rather, reseeding the bit generator gives reproducible results. Why is this the case? What am I doing wrong?" you're not using the generator you've recreated. You create a new generator but you keep using the "legacy" singleton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, when you recreate the `RandomState` object, you are not using it when taking random numbers.

When you create the `RandomState` you are not reseeding the whole numpy env.
But rather creating a new random generator object.

Change you code to:

```
# Recreate a BitGenerator
rs1 = RandomState(MT19937(SeedSequence(seed)))
c1 = rs1.random_integers(1, 6, 1000)
rs2 = RandomState(MT19937(SeedSequence(seed)))
c2 = rs2.random_integers(1, 6, 1000)
```

Comment: And unless you need compatibility with older MT-using sequences, you might as well switch to PCG which is objectively better on every axis (better statistical properties, faster, less memory).

Comment: I wish NumPy's document append your example to their example. :) Much more easier to understand. ;)